# Can two sequences of r.v be asymptotically equivalent?

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, notation

I wanted to ask if the following notations make sense and/or are used.

Convergence in distribution of a sequence $X_n$ of real random variables to the random variable $X$ is often indicated like this:

$X_n \overset{\mbox{D}}{\longrightarrow} X$

and this would imply that for any measurable set $U$ in $R$:

$P(\{ X_n \in U\}) \rightarrow P(\{ X \in U\})$

( Here the convergence is standard sequence convergence in $R$. I think this follows from the pointwise convergence of the c.d.f. but you may correct me if I am wrong )

I wonder if the following notation is used/makes sense to define asymptotic equivalence of two series of r.v. :

$X_n \sim_D Y_n$

with the meaning that for any set $U$:

$P(\{ X_n \in U\}) \sim P(\{ Y_n \in U\})$

where two real sequences $x_n,y_n$ are equivalent if $lim_n \frac{x_n}{y_n}=1$

Or also, with a similar meaning, the more exotic notation can be used ?:

$X_n \sim_D f_n$

where $f_n$ are distributions ?

EDIT: For example, using these notations one could write the C.L.T. like this. Instead of:

$\frac{S_n-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}\rightarrow_DZ$

we could say:

$S_n \sim_D N(\mu,\sigma/\sqrt{n})$

I think I have seen such a notation used somewhere but I am not sure how much such a thing is rigorous... hence my question actually...

Comment: (The $U$'s there must be *measurable* and such that $P(X\in\partial U)=0$.)

Comment: Thanks. Measurability should be there of course. If you have a reference about the second condition, that would enrich the question :)

Comment: See the [Portmanteau theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_measures).

Comment: @nejimban any feedback on the other part of the question?

Comment: I can't tell if such definitions would be interesting, at least I never encountered them. And it doesn't seem to greatly simplify the “algebra” on weak convergence of random variables.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience. I have written an example in the question. I think I have seen such a notation also recently in this site, even if I cannot recall the question... do you think it makes sense that notation ?

Comment: That notation $S_n \sim_D N(\mu,\sigma/\sqrt{n})$ makes sense and we can guess what it means. I just wonder if it is really useful, because we already have the notation $\frac{S_n-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}\stackrel D\to N(\mu,\sigma)$.

Comment: You should have $N(0,1)$ on the right in the C.L.T.  If the notation "makes sense" it must be officially defined, but I find no reference. For real sequences the notation $x_n \rightarrow y_n$ is not used, but we have $x_n \sim y_n$ with a well defined meaning. Is there something similar for random variables/distributions ?

Comment: I just meant that it can look natural to understand $S_n \sim_D N(\mu,\sigma/\sqrt{n})$ as a “shortcut” for $\frac{S_n-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}\stackrel D\to N(0,1)$. Whether it is useful to make such a shortcut, I don't know. You may want to look at Berry-Esseen bounds for how close $S_n$ is to $N(\mu,\sigma/\sqrt{n})$ in the CLT.

Comment: Ah ok. But the notation that I have in mind is more than a shortcut notation for the CLT, it is a general notation for asymptotic equivalent of r.v.  . The CLT is just an example...

Comment: The point is that often one finds expressions like $X_n \sim f_n$, with some distributions $f_n$, and I wonder if these notations have a general meaning. Hence my question.