# Notation about convergence of random variables

Tags: probability, notation, random-variables

This is a simplification of this question [Can two sequences of r.v be asymptotically equivalent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4358212/can-two-sequences-of-r-v-be-asymptotically-equivalent) , in order to favour contributions without having a long question.

The central limit theorem is stated often like this, using the well defined limit in distribution.

$\frac{S_n-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}\rightarrow_DZ$

Does this alternative notation makes sense ? Is it rigorous and can it be used ? What mathematical meaning would one give to such a notation ?

$S_n \sim N(\mu,\sigma/\sqrt{n})$

Answer (score 1):

The tilde $\sim$ most commonly has the meaning "has the probability distribution of," so using it for an asymptotic statement only serves to confuse.

Subscripting the tilde by a "D" (as you do in the other link) avoids this issue, but I don't see how you would generalize the notation

$$S_n\sim_D N(\mu,\sigma^2/n)$$

to other asymptotic distributions.

Comment: Thanks @Golden_Ratio for writing this down in an answer. Indeed I used the subscript D in the other question but here I removed it to keep the notation more "underfined". If I find circumstances where such a notation is used I will update the question with a reference...